# can we run node js child process with code instead of file or command?

Tags: node.js, child-process

### I have a situation, in which I want to run some code (some call to API), in child process. So, can we run code in a child process instead of file or command ? -- old

Now I have used this code:

```
<code>process = require('child_process');
                var ls = process.spawnSync('node','lookUp.js ' + serialNumber);
                ls.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                 console.log('stdout: ' + data);
                }); </code>
```

And received this erroe :

```
<code>
child_process.js:1254
  for (i = 0; i < options.stdio.length; i++) {
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.spawnSync (child_process.js:1254:32)
    at /home/eweba1-pc-22/htdocs/geoAdmin/myAdminTester/zohocrm-myadmin-module-to-get-devices/service2.js:252:22
    at Object.whilst (/home/eweba1-pc-22/htdocs/geoAdmin/myAdminTester/zohocrm-myadmin-module-to-get-devices/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:4578:9)
    at Request._callback (/home/eweba1-pc-22/htdocs/geoAdmin/myAdminTester/zohocrm-myadmin-module-to-get-devices/service2.js:211:10)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/eweba1-pc-22/htdocs/geoAdmin/myAdminTester/zohocrm-myadmin-module-to-get-devices/node_modules/request/request.js:200:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/eweba1-pc-22/htdocs/geoAdmin/myAdminTester/zohocrm-myadmin-module-to-get-devices/node_modules/request/request.js:1067:10)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/eweba1-pc-22/htdocs/geoAdmin/myAdminTester/zohocrm-myadmin-module-to-get-devices/node_modules/request/request.js:988:12)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:129:20)
</code>
```

Comment: do you want to run js code as a background task?

Comment: yes, but synch mode

Comment: child_process.fork(modulePath[, args][, options]) in the documentation it says it can take only a path. put your code into a file then give that file path as modulePath.

Comment: I need to pass some arguments to that code and arguments are in object form

Comment: I have updated my post and getting this new error